# Symmetry towards Y axis in Series VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, plot, charts, axes

I have plot done some plots using Chart object and SeriesCollection.NewSeries
The portion of the code is like this

```
Private Function AddSeriesAndFormats(PPSChart As Chart, shInfo As Worksheet, tests() As PPS_Test, RowCount As Integer, col As Integer, smoothLine As Boolean, lineStyle As String, transparency As Integer, lineWidth As Single, ByRef position As Integer) As Series

Dim mySeries As Series

Set mySeries = PPSChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
With mySeries
    .Name = tests(0).GetString()
    .XValues = "='" & shInfo.Name & "'!R" & RowCount - UBound(tests) - 1 & "C" & CInt(4 * (col + 1) - 2) & ":R" & RowCount - 1 & "C" & CInt(4 * (col + 1) - 2)
    .Values = "='" & shInfo.Name & "'!R" & RowCount - UBound(tests) - 1 & "C" & CInt(4 * (col + 1) - 1) & ":R" & RowCount - 1 & "C" & CInt(4 * (col + 1) - 1)
    .Smooth = smoothLine
    .Format.line.Weight = lineWidth
    .Format.line.DashStyle = GetLineStyle(lineStyle)
    .Format.line.transparency = CSng(transparency / 100)
    .MarkerStyle = SetMarkerStyle(position)
    .MarkerSize = 9
    .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
End With

Set AddSeriesAndFormats = mySeries

End Function
```

and the PPSChart is created like this

```
Private Function AddChartAndFormatting(chartName As String, chartTitle As String, integralBuffer As Integer, algoPropertyName As String) As Chart

Dim PPSChart As Chart, mySeries As Series

Set PPSChart = Charts.Add
With PPSChart
    .Name = chartName
    .HasTitle = True
    .chartTitle.Characters.Text = chartTitle
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    If algoPropertyName <> "" Then 'case for Generic PPS plots
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = algoPropertyName
    Else
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "PL/PR max(avg_" & integralBuffer & "ms) [mbar]" 'case for the bumper obsolate algorithm
    End If
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Bumper Position [mm]"
End With

' delete random series that might be generated
For Each mySeries In PPSChart.SeriesCollection
    mySeries.Delete
Next mySeries

Set AddChartAndFormatting = PPSChart

End Function
```

An example of the result is like in this picture below
[image]
What I want is to have the X axis starting from -350, even that I do not have values in the left side of the Y axis (in the negative side). Practically, what I want to have is the Y axis in the middle, even if the plotted values are positive (symmetry between maximum X value and minimum X value towards Y axis). 
Can You tell me if it is possible and give me some examples?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you could try something like this:

```
Dim dMinValue as Double, dMaxValue as Double

With PPSChart
    dMinValue = application.WorksheetFunction.Min("='" & _
                    shInfo.Name & "'!R" & RowCount - UBound(tests) - 1 _ 
                    & "C" & CInt(4 * (col + 1) - 2) & ":R" & RowCount - 1  _
                    & "C" & CInt(4 * (col + 1) - 2))

    dMaxValue = application.WorksheetFunction.Max("='" & _
                    shInfo.Name & "'!R" & RowCount - UBound(tests) - 1 _ 
                    & "C" & CInt(4 * (col + 1) - 2) & ":R" & RowCount - 1  _
                    & "C" & CInt(4 * (col + 1) - 2))
    ....
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = dMinValue
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = dMaxValue
    ....
End With
```

My advice, you should assign your Series Values to an object for easy use

```
Dim rSerie as Range
Set rSerie = Range("='" & _
                        shInfo.Name & "'!R" & RowCount - UBound(tests) - 1 _ 
                        & "C" & CInt(4 * (col + 1) - 2) & ":R" & RowCount - 1  _
                        & "C" & CInt(4 * (col + 1) - 2)))

With ....
    dMinValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rSerie)
    ....
End with
```

Comment: It's a little difficult because first I create chart and after that I read the values and create the series. This code: .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = dMinValue
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = dMaxValue  works only when create the chart and not when you create the series.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AddChartObject()
    Dim myChtObj As ChartObject

    Set myChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
        (Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
    myChtObj.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:G14")
    myChtObj.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

    ' delete random series that might be generated
    For Each mySeries In myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
        mySeries.Delete
    Next mySeries

    ' add series
    Set mySeries = myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    mySeries.XValues = Array(0, 300)
    mySeries.Values = Array(88, 65)

    ' rescale axis after adding series
    With myChtObj.Chart.Axes(xlCategory) ' otherwise can use ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
        .MinimumScale = -350 'ActiveSheet.Range("C33").Value
        .MaximumScale = 350 'ActiveSheet.Range("D54").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: symmetrical horizontal axis]